# Pod files are missing

Tags: xcode

I am new in iOS dev, but I need to build a certain project. The problem is that when I click on the build button xcode fails and one of the errors says

```
Unable to load content of list : path_to_pod_file
```

as well I see that in project structure xcode marked missing files with red color

[image]

I read about pod files and understood that it is a kind of configuration file, so the question is: are these files should be generated by build (somehow) or it is files that I hadn't received with a project and there is no way to generate them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution here:

https://medium.com/@soufianerafik/how-to-add-pods-to-an-xcode-project-2994aa2abbf1#

Actually, the files I asked for above are generated and I needed to install the pod and run the Pod file which (in my case) was under my project structure.

1. sudo gem install cocoapods
2. cd PATH_TO_YOUR_PROJECT_FOLDER
3. pod init (IN CASE IF YOU HAVEN'T ALREADY HAVE IT)
4. pod install
5. Double click on the Xcode workspace to open the project
6. You can clean/re-build your project and run it.